# Dealing with missing islands when mapping a geographical map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I want to create a geographical map of California that also includes the Channel Islands in R using ggplot2 (not the base package). When I use `map_data` to get the state of California. It does not include the Channel Islands. How do I get the islands on the map? Seems like I can use `raster` to extract level 2 data but I am not sure how to merge these two polygons to get one map containing the state and the islands?

`library(maps)`
`library(ggplot2)`

`states <- map_data("state")`

`CA <- subset(states, region %in% c("California"))`

`ggplot() +  geom_polygon(data = CA, aes(x=long, y = lat)) +  coord_fixed(1.3) + coord_sf(xlim = c(-125, -117.5), ylim = c(32.5, 39.5), expand = FALSE)`

Comment: Hello vita, there's no californian islands in your dataset

Comment: Not quite sure if this is helpful but switching to library(leaflet) allows for control on basemaps m <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(lng= -119.7785, lat=34.0069, popup="Channel Islands National Park") %>% 
  setView(lng = -120, lat = 34, zoom =6) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.NatGeoWorldMap)
m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{rnaturalearth} and the associated packages contain island information, at least for the U.S.A. Here is an example

```
  world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
  ggplot2::ggplot(data = world) +
    ggplot2::geom_sf() +
    ggplot2::coord_sf(
      xlim = c(-127.15, -116.50),
      ylim = c(31.90, 49.50),
      expand = FALSE
    )
```